# Does magento update paypal with tracking information?

Tags: shipping, paypal

I'm trying to determine if magento will update paypal with tracking when a shipment is created.  My work flow right now is as follows.

Orders created on Magento site via paypal advanced.

Order is captured by THUB and a shipping label is created. A shipment is created on magento which sends the appropriate emails out.

It's at this point that I have to manually copy the tracking number over to paypal.  Shouldn't magento send paypal the tracking information when a shipment is created?

Any help or suggestions is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no PayPal API created to handle it for now.
You need to keep an eye on API updates here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/

Comment: please  try to give some more details, so that future visitors will also benefit from your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, however since this is the top and possibly the only question on StackExchange regarding this subject, I'm going to paste my answer that I just put on the Adobe Magento Forum, but who know how long they will be available.

Due to Magento using the NVP Soap to take payments, you'll need to create a REST api APP.

The APP is super easy to make in Paypal.
https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox

https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/live

Attached is the code I've just written to test the functionality. It's pretty simple, but could easily be put into an after create shipment event and check the payment method is Paypal.

You'll need to load your order with something like

\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$getLastTransId = $order->getPayment()->getLastTransId();

$tracksCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();
$trackNumber = '';

foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $track) {

    $trackNumber = $track->getTrackNumber();
    $trackTitle = $track->getTitle();
}

$content = [
"trackers" => [[
"transaction_id" => $getLastTransId,
"tracking_number" => $trackNumber,
"status" => "SHIPPED",
"carrier" => $trackTitle
 ]]
];

$pp_client_id = 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID';
$pp_secret = 'YOUR-SECRET';

$ch = curl_init();
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $pp_client_id.':'.$pp_secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
'grant_type'=>'client_credentials',
)));

$res_authcode = curl_exec($ch);

if (empty($res_authcode)) {
echo 'Unable to login'; exit;
} else {
$json_authcode = json_decode($res_authcode, true);
$access_token = $json_authcode['access_token'];

if(empty($access_token)) {
echo 'No Token Provided'; exit;
} else {

// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers-batch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/shipping/trackers-batch');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($content));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,
'content-type: application/json'
));

$res_trackinfo = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($res_trackinfo)) {
echo 'Unable to post shipping data'; exit;
} else {
$res_trackinfo = json_decode($res_trackinfo);
 print_r($res_trackinfo, true); exit;
}
}

curl_close($ch);

}
```